# Remove duplicate value from combobox which is dynamically created

Tags: javascript, html, combobox

I have a combo box, which has got some values, also I have some few values, I select one value from combo box and do some manipulation and come back with the value selected (set these values in session). Now I need to automatically select the value which are in session in the combo box.

I have followed the below JavaScript and it works fine but it creates a duplicate value which is already in the combo box:

```
function addCombo() {
    var reportID = '<%=reportid%>';
    var reportName = '<%=reportname%>';

    var textb = document.getElementById("reportnames");

    var option = document.createElement("option");
    option.text = reportName;
    option.value = reportID;
    option.selected='selected';
    try {
        textb.add(option, null); //Standard
    }catch(error) {
        textb.add(option); // IE only
    }
    textb.value = "";
}
```

Could anyone help me to identify?

Comment: this link may help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4590311/set-option-selected-attribute-from-dynamic-created-option

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have not removed the value rather i added the following code, it solved me the problem.

```
function addCombo() {
    var reportID = '<%=reportid%>';
    var options= document.getElementById('reportnames').options;
    for (var i= 0, n= options.length; i < n ; i++) {
        if (options[i].value==reportID) {
            document.getElementById("reportnames").selectedIndex = i;
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

understand ok try:

```
function addCombo() {
    var reportID = 'aa';
    var reportName = 'aa';

    var textb = document.getElementById("reportnames");
    var option = document.createElement("option");

    if (hasValue(textb, reportID)) (function() {


        // selected attr remove
        for (var i=textb.options.length-1; i >= 0; i--) (function() {

            if (textb.options[i].selected == true) (function() {

                textb.options[i].removeAttribute("selected");
            }());
        }());

        option.text = reportName;
        option.value = reportID;

        // selected new option element 
        option.setAttribute("selected", "selected");


        try {
            textb.add(option, null); //Standard
        } catch(error) {
            textb.add(option); // IE only
        };

        /*
        *  I do not understand selected added option value "" ?? 
        */ 
        //textb.value = "";

       }());
};
```

hasValue function:

```
function hasValue(element, value) {
    var results = true;

    for (var i=element.options.length-1; i >= 0; i--) (function() {

        if (element.options[i].value == value) (function() { 
            results = false;
        }());
    }());

    return (results);
};
```

take it easy..