# /!\ Resolve /!\ Create a select with option selected in JS

Tags: javascript, select, selected

[Resolve]
Ok i find the problem ... am so stupid -_-
Sorry for that (after i creat the select, i call a function who set the selectedIndex to 0 ...).

i try to create a select with JS (all is ok here) but i can't selected a specific option ! I have try all solutions but nothing work ...

Here is my code:
reponse is a table with all my options.

```
function creatSelect(reponse) {

    var name_div = document.getElementById('ChooseModele');
    var select = document.createElement("select");
    select.setAttribute("name", "ListModele");
    select.setAttribute("id", "ListModele");
    select.style.width = "300px";
    select.setAttribute("onchange", 'updateModele(this.options[this.selectedIndex].value)');
    var option = document.createElement("option");
    option.setAttribute("value", "");
    option.innerHTML = "";
    select.appendChild(option);
    for (var nbmessage=0;nbmessage<reponse.length;nbmessage++)
        {
        option = document.createElement("option");
        option.setAttribute("value", reponse[nbmessage].name);
        option.innerHTML = reponse[nbmessage].name;
        if(reponse[nbmessage].name=='**modele i want selected**')
            **option.setAttribute("selected","selected");**
        select.appendChild(option);
        }
    name_div.appendChild(select);

}
```

Comment: I would like to suggest you to use jQuery, it will make your life easier :)

Comment: take a look at [this][1] SO. It asks something like you need.


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4590311/set-option-selected-attribute-from-dynamic-created-option

Comment: Did you check whether the `if` part is ever reached (you will need `{}` for the `if` to test)? Does the condition ever become true? Basic debugging. Also, `setAttribute("onchange", "")` is a terrible idea, you should not do that. Event handling is a powerful feature of the DOM, you should use it (google `addEventListener`).

Comment: One more thing: [your code works fine](http://jsfiddle.net/bazmegakapa/YKqLm/). I only modified the `if` condition in your code, to match my data. Tried in Chrome and IE11.

Comment: Hi, yes i reach the if (use an alert for debbug). It's strange because for me it's not workink in IE, firefox ...

Comment: @user3364054 Please check my jsfiddle then, it might help you find the real problem. Your code should be working, if the condition is right. Checked in Firefox too, it is fine.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the `element.options[index].selected` property.

So, try this: (untested)

```
function creatSelect(reponse) {

    var name_div = document.getElementById('ChooseModele');
    var select = document.createElement("select");
    select.setAttribute("name", "ListModele");
    select.setAttribute("id", "ListModele");
    select.style.width = "300px";
    select.setAttribute("onchange", 'updateModele(this.options[this.selectedIndex].value)');
    var option = document.createElement("option");
    option.setAttribute("value", "");
    option.innerHTML = "";
    select.appendChild(option);
    var selectedIndex = 0;
    for (var nbmessage=0;nbmessage<reponse.length;nbmessage++)
        {
        option = document.createElement("option");
        option.setAttribute("value", reponse[nbmessage].name);
        option.innerHTML = reponse[nbmessage].name;
        if(reponse[nbmessage].name=='**modele i want selected**')
            selectedIndex = nbMessage; // save the selected option index
        select.appendChild(option);
        }
    select.options[selectedIndex].selected = true; // here, you set the default selected option
    name_div.appendChild(select);

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code is working fine (I tested with latest Chrome on that fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/enJ5F/1/)

Just for fun, here is a solution using jQuery:

```
function createSelect(response) {
    var $select = $( "<select>" ).appendTo($( "#ChooseModele" ));
    $.each(response, function(key, value) {
        var selected = value.name == 'modele i want selected';
        $( "<option>", { value: value.name, selected: selected } )
            .text( value.name )
            .appendTo( $select );
    });
}
```

A fiddle that show how it works: http://jsfiddle.net/ny6m5/

Answer (score 0):

you can keep the `option's index`, and after loop, select `option` by **`index`**:

```
var selectedIndex = 0;
for (var nbmessage=0;nbmessage<reponse.length;nbmessage++)
{
    if(reponse[nbmessage].name=='**modele i want selected**')
        selectedIndex = nbmessage;
}

select.selectedIndex = selectedIndex;
```