# Bigcommerce Template: How to dynamically control 'Quantity' per item?

Tags: javascript, jquery, bigcommerce

I am modifying a Bigcommerce template. The requirement is to modify the selected value in Quantity dropdown based on other inputs by users. (I have achieved that in jsfiddle (http://jsfiddle.net/xuC6f/14/)). 
Question is: How do I, in bigcommerce template, control Quantity? i.e.,

```
$("#qty_").val(keyTechPercentage);
```

When I check the Source Code, it seems there's an ITEM_ID that's attached to QTY_ that makes it look like

```
<select id="qty_53df2e8f36bb9" ...>
```

Thanks a lot in advance!

Comment: @QuentinEngles, No, it doesn't...

Comment: What's keeping you from copying that id and using it then.

Comment: The ID would be different for each item (am sorry, if that's what you meant to ask earlier), though it may be the same for the ID across time and space.

Comment: Does the parent of your select have a consistent id? If so you can select that instead to get at the quantity value. That being said I still don't know what problem you're having.

Comment: I think I see what your problem is now. Try this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4590311/set-option-selected-attribute-from-dynamic-created-option

Comment: On  your fiddle I changed it with     var opt = $("#qty_").val(7).selected();

Comment: I've also changed it with     var opt = $(".AddCartButton select").val(9).selected();

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These will do it.

```
var opt = $("#qty_").val(7).selected();

var opt = $(".AddCartButton select").val(9).selected();
```