# Make <select> option selected

Tags: html

I have an HTML form with list of countries, now in profile I want to make selected country that user selected when registered to site. I'm searhed google but I can't make anything works.

In profile I'm selecting Country Value from MySQL

Comment: can you please explain more about your question???

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to set `select` statically then use this

```
<form>
  <select>
    <option value="value" selected="selected">01</option>
    <option value="value" >02</option>
  </select>
</form>
```

Or if you want to do dynamically then [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4590311/set-option-selected-attribute-from-dynamic-created-option) may be helpful.
Hope this will work for you ...

Answer (score 2):

Put [a `selected` attribute](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/forms.html#attr-option-selected) in the option you want to be selected.

```
<option value="foo" selected> bar </option>
```

Comment: I know this but in script i'm selecting value of Country from MySQL, I can't make selected tag foreach Country

Comment: @MiljanIlic — No, you use the **attribute** for the one that matches. (Which you'll usually generate using a loop in your script).

Comment: Is tehere any way to insert that tag without editing list of >180 options?

Comment: "using a loop in your script" (and if you don't have the options in a structured data format already, put them in one… using a regex over your HTML if need be).