# How to add "selected" to select option using javascript

Tags: javascript

I have the following code and I am trying to add "selected" to the  option dynamically, when the user select an option. How can i do it using Javascript ?
Example when the user select "Candy" I want to add  `<option value="candy" selected>Candy</option>`

```js
function urlDirect() {
  var businessTypeSelected = document.getElementById("BusinessType").value;
  //alert("x " +x);
  if (businessTypeSelected != "") {
    window.location.href = location.host + businessTypeSelected;
    document.getElementById("BusinessType").selectedIndex = document.getElementById("BusinessType").selectedIndex;
  } else {

  }
}
```

```html
<span class="custom-dropdown custom-dropdown--blue custom-dropdown--large">
  <select id="BusinessType" class="custom-dropdown__select custom-dropdown__select--blue" onChange="urlDirect()">
    <option value="default">Select your business type</option>
    <option value="auto">Auto </option>
    <option value="aero">Aeroplane</option>
    <option value="film">Film</option>
    <option value="candy">Candy</option>
  </select>
</span>
```

Comment: [Possible duplicate](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4590311/set-option-selected-attribute-from-dynamic-created-option)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This should do:

```
var select = document.getElementById('BusinessType');
select.addEventListener('change', function() {

  select.options[select.selectedIndex].setAttribute('selected');
});
```

Also I'd suggest you change the name of the `id` to `business-type` since CSS isn't written in camelCase.

Comment: how will it remember what the user has selected? as each page will have the same drop down /combo box?

Comment: That's for another question. My answer is for the question you have provided.

Answer (score 0):

```
var select = document.getElementById('BusinessType');
select.options[indexOfoption].selected = true;
```

You can do it by this method too. it's easy to understand